Google Chrome windows don't restore to their last Space on macOS Sequoia
Previously, as described in How can I make OSX remember the desktop assignment of different chrome windows, you could use:
defaults write com.google.Chrome NSWindowRestoresWorkspaceAtLaunch -bool YES

to have Chrome windows restore to the Space they were last open on when Chrome restarted.
When you didn't set this option, on restart all Chrome windows would reopen on the Space you were currently on (i.e. all your Chrome windows would end up on one single Space, even if you had previously had windows on multiple different Spaces).
Since macOS 15 Sequoia, this option does not seem to function anymore: all Chrome windows reopen on the same Space even when NSWindowRestoresWorkspaceAtLaunch is set to YES.
Does anyone know a way to restore this functionality?

This Chromium bug reports looks at least related: #369865047 Restore Google Chrome windows to their respective virtual desktops (macOS)

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Thanks... yes, that's definitely related and is probably the same root cause. (I would upvote this but don't have enough reputation. )
